# remove NSArray element depending on its value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSArray of NSDictionary values they NSDictionay structure looks like this

```
ID = 22;
SERIESID = 33;
YEAREND = 2002;
YEARSTART = 1996;
```

I have a dozen or so of these elements in my array, I would like to know how to remove elements who had the same **SERIESID** from the NSArray or if this is even possible after the NSArray is already made.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well first off, you should only be removing objects from a ***NSMutableArray***, not an immutable NSArray.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. "remove elements who had the same SERIESID from the NSArray"? You said that the `NSMutableArray` contained these dictionaries. Do you mean if the same value is present in multiple dictionaries in the array?

Comment: good point... that can be changed :P luckly :)

Comment: Do you really want to remove every element that has the same SERIESID as some other element, or do you want to remove all but one?

Comment: @Chuck I would like to remove all but one. Sorry about the lack of clarity.. some times I think of it but i just dont write it down in a coherent way. lol

Comment: @TheKraken so I have noe changed it to be a NSMutableArray, I would like to remove any NSDictionary that has the same SERIESID following the first one that is read.. from what I can tell there is never an occasion where they are in a random order.. so my NSMutable has 8 objects but in fact it only has 4 as the 1 object repeates so is the same as the second object then the 3 repeates to be the 4th as well and so on... I want to remove those duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, iterate through the array, keeping track of the SERIESID you have seen, and if the current element's SERIESID is a duplicate, you mark it to be deleted.

Like so:

```
NSMutableSet *seen = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableIndexSet *toDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
[yourArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id dict, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([seen containsObject:dict[@"SERIESID"]]) {
        [toDelete addIndex:i];
    } else {
        [seen addObject:dict[@"SERIESID"]];
    }
}];
[yourArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:toDelete];
```

(As a side note, you'll have to do the deletion this way even though it isn't the most intuitive approach. NSMutableArray isn't designed to be changed while you're in the middle of looping through it, so you'll get errors if you just try using `removeObjectAtIndex:` in your loop. That's why we build up a list of objects we want to delete and then hand it to the array at the end.)

Comment: Haha, great minds think alike. Looks like you managed to hit the return button just a bit faster. :) +1 for the use of enumeration.

Comment: okay just going to try this out now.. I will let you know how I go just gonna have a byte to eat so might be 30 minutes or so.

Comment: yup this worked perfectly.. sorry for the late reply had lunch in the middle of it all and almost forgot tocome back lol

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but you could do something similar to this:

```
NSMutableArray *seriesHolder = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in yourMutableArray)
{
   NSString *seriesID = [dict objectForKey:@"SERIESID"];

   if(![seriesHolder containsObject:seriesID])
   {
     [seriesHolder addObject:seriesID];
   }
   else
   {
     [yourMutableArray removeObject:dict];
   } 
}
```

Comment: This will work, but I'd point to @Chuck's answer instead. This is exactly the kind of thing `NSSet` was made for, rather than arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `NSMutableSet` to contain used values of `SERIESID`. Run a `for` loop through every dictionary in the array. As you iterate through each dictionary, check the object of the dictionary's `SERIESID` key. If it isn't already present in the set, add it. If it is already present, then remove that object from the array. When the itteration finishes, you will have only one object in the array for each value of `SERIESID`. Note that obviously the this will mean that the first instance of a dictionary with a unique `SERIESID` will be the one that is kept, so be sure you have the dictionaries in a viable order before you iterate through the array.

If you need more particular information on the precise methods needed to accomplish this, check out the [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html)